# How to have exception object as parameter to ActionMessage in Struts 1.3

Tags: string, exception, struts-1

My actual requirement is that if the application is not able to create a DB connection, then an error message saying "Unable to create DB connection" should be displayed in the UI. So I wrote a class which throws a user-defined `DBConnectionException`. I wrote the below lines in my `ActionMessages` class:

```
ActionMesssages messages = new ActionMessages();
try {
    schedule = scheduleDAO.getSchedule();
} catch (DBConnectionException e) {
    messages.add("scheduleDelete", new ActionMessage(e.getMessage()));
}
```

I am getting the exception, but it looks like:

> `???en_US.Unable to create DB connection???`

I am getting this since I don't have the key `Unable to create DB connection` in my `ApplicationResouces.properties` file. My question is:

Is it possible to have a string instead of key in `ActionMessage`? All the constructors of `ActionMessage` is with a key. How to directly add a string to `ActionMessages`? Or suggest me a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

Create a message, pass the key, and pass the exception message as a replacement value.

That said, I'd be extremely cautious about passing exception information directly to the user, even if it *is* an app-specific exception you've created. IMO it'd be better to decouple your exceptions, which are intended for *developer* consumption, from your messages, which are intended for normal people.